# Saving multiple instances of models in a rails form using CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a form that has multiple instances of different models at once.

I have my main model visualizations. A Visualization (:title, :cover_image) has_many Rows. A Row has_many Panes (:text_field, :image)

Basically when a user tries to create a Visualization, they can choose the cover image and title easily enough. But I get a bit confused when I come to the next two levels.

The user is prompted to create a new Row in the form and they can choose either 1, 2, or 3 Panes per Row. Each pane can take in text and an image, but Row doesn't necessarily have any attributes itself.

How can I generate multiple Rows with multiple Panes in this form? The end result will need to possess a bunch of rows consisting of many panes. Can I even do this in rails?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes, Rails is great at this.  `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is what you need to read up on.

Comment: Refer to rails guide to build complex forms [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do anything in rails!  The best approach in my opinion is to create what is known as a Form Model since this form will have a lot going on and you don't want to bog down several models with validations and such for one view of your app.  To do this you're basically going to create a class that will take all of this information in, run whatever validations you need, and then create whatever records you need in whatever models you have.  To do this lets create a new file in your model folder called `so_much.rb`  (You can make any filename you want just make sure you name the class the same as the file so Rails finds it automagically!)

Then in your so_much.rb file do:

```
class SoMuch
    include ActiveModel::Model #This gives us rails validations & model helpers
    attr_accessor :visual_title
    attr_accessor :visual_cover #These are virtual attributes so you can make as many as needed to handle all of your form fields.  Obviously these aren't tied to a database table so we'll run our validations and then save them to their proper models as needed below!
    #Add whatever other form fields youll have

    validate :some_validator_i_made

    def initialize(params={})
       self.visual_title = params[:visual_title]
       self.visual_cover = params[:visual_cover]
       #Assign whatever fields you added here
    end

    def some_validator_i_made
        if self.visual_title.blank?
           errors.add(:visual_title, "This can't be blank!")
        end
    end

end
```

Now you can go into your controller that is processing this form and do something like:

```
def new
  @so_much = SoMuch.new
end

def create
     user_input = SoMuch.new(form_params)
     if user_input.valid? #This runs our validations before we try to save
        #Save the params to their appropriate models
     else
        @errors = user_input.errors
     end
end

private

def form_params
    params.require(@so_much).permit(all your virtual attributes we just made here)
end
```

Then in your view you would set your form_for up with `@so_much` like:

```
 <%= form_for @so_much do %> 
     whatever virtual attributes etc
  <% end %>
```

Form Models are a bit advanced in  Rails but are a life saver when it comes to larger apps where you have many different types of forms for one model and you don't want all of the clutter.

Comment: Wow thanks this is awesome!

So I need to make a SoMuch controller, not throw that code in my Visualizations controller right?

Comment: No problem.  No you want to keep your controller that handles your views, the SoMuch class you created is just a tableless model that you'll perform validations on in your code.  Use your normal controller and actions in them and just call the SoMuch class from it as shown.

Comment: I see your new to stack so just another tip which you may already know, all model classes are available in all of your controllers.

Comment: Oops I had one more question. So in my views I can just list as many copies of attributes as I want? E.g. I can just put a form for rows 8 times and within those rows I can put up to 3 panes each time?

Comment: Yep whatever attributes you list in your views you need to name them differently (like :pane_1 and :pane_2) and then make virtual attributes for them in your SoMuch class as shown (attr_accessor :pane_1).  Mark the answer as correct if you're good to go!

Comment: Sorry for all the questions as I'm very new to rails. When I'm labeling these things do I need to nest them somehow? So since Visualizations Model has Rows and Rows Model have Panes, is there some specific syntax I need for adding the attr_accessor's/fields? Since row only has an optional "title" field but owns panes, I see other people suggested I look into nested_attributes, does this bypass all of that because of the "rails magic" I keep hearing? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: This will validate everything as you need however when saving the records to certain models you'll want to do something like:    Visualization.rows.create(some_visual_attribute: params[:att_here], some_row_attribute_or_id: params[:att_for_row_here)   and just add "accepts_nested_attributes_for :rows  in your Visualization model.